# rimraf installs successfully but rimraf command not found on Windows

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

I've installed rimraf several times and on several machines. It installs the package successfully. When I'm using rimraf command, it errors out as "'rimraf' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

I've tried installing as administrator and user, using both npm and yarn. It installs well as you can see in the below code. But the command is not recognized.

> npm install -g rimraf
>   C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\rimraf -> C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\rimraf\bin.js
>    + rimraf@2.6.3
>   updated 1 package in 1.695s
>
> rimraf
>   'rimraf' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Comment: Install this package globally on your system & restart the command prompt.

Comment: you can see in the post I have installed it globally, it gets installed but `rimraf` command does not run as its not recognized.

Answer (score 0):

check the version of node js installed, set nodejs path in the environment variables, then reopen the command window, type npm if it works then rimraf also work, hope it helps, thanks